# Deleting Facebook App requests doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My facebook app sends out requests to some users who have not yet added the app themselves. When they accept the request, I am trying to delete it. At this moment, they have already (automatically) added the app and authorized it to use their information and so on.

I am trying to delete the request exactly like it is described in the documentation:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
    $reqs = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);
    foreach($reqs as $r) {
        $full_req_id = $r . '_' . $this->_currentfbuser->getId();
        $delete_success = $this->_facebook->api("/" . $full_req_id,'DELETE');
    }
}
```

I double-checked that `$full_req_id` really is `request-id_user-id`, but I am still getting this error:

```
Message: (#200) The entity backed by id ... cannot be seen by the current viewer (EntID: ...)
```

Why is it forbidden for my app to delete the request? Shouldn't it always be allowed to delete requests sent by the same app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using this snippet. (I thought, the Facebook SDK would be doing roughly the same internally, but anyways)

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
    $reqs = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);
    foreach($reqs as $r) {
        $full_req_id = $r . '_' . $this->_currentfbuser->getId();
        $delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" .
            $full_req_id . "?access_token=" . $this->_facebook->getAccessToken() . "&method=delete";

        $result = file_get_contents($delete_url);
    }
}
```